# localhost redirecting to path specified for sub domain

Tags: apache, cakephp, localhost, wamp

In cakephp, I want to redirect localhost to app2 and client1.localhost to app1.
Instead both are redirecting to app1.

my httpd-vhost is defined as:

```
    NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\cakephp\app2\webroot\
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.myhost> 
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\app1\webroot"
    ServerName client1.localhost
    ServerAlias client1.localhost
    <Directory "D:\wamp\app1\webroot">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what version of cake are you using?

Comment: i am using cakephp 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance there are a few weird things with your vhost config:

- The first document root has no closing "
- the virtualhost names should both be the same
- your referring to the webroot, instead of the approot (there's also a .htacces in your approot)

I use CakePHP 2.x with wamp server with a configuration like this:

make sure the vhost file is uncommented in your apache configuration:
wamp/bin/apache/Apache[version]/conf/httpd.conf (or left click wamp->apache->httpd.conf)

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Try this in wamp/bin/apache/Apache[version]/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#    
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName client1.localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\app1"
    <Directory "D:\wamp\app1">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\cakephp\app2"

    <Directory "D:\wamp\www\cakephp\app2">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

and put this in your hosts file (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc)

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.localhost
127.0.0.1       client1.localhost
```

Do a wamp restart all services.
App2 will be available on both localhost and dev.localhost

Comment: @Jeron What must be added to the httpd.conf to specify the virtual host.. I tried using the configuration given in apache.org only client1.localhost is working, the localhost is throwing 500 error.

Comment: when I made this answer I thought this was quite weird, but that is how it works on my PC. I'll try to find the setting that does this. In httpd.conf I've set "ServerName localhost:80" and other settings are still the same (they all point to default wamp places. I'm not unsing the default www dir.)